# How to deal with a Windows path given as an argument

Tags: python, click, pathlib

I have a script that takes a file path as an argument and I'm having issues with how to handle Windows paths in this situation.  How do I avoid a situation like this `"T:\not\a\good\path"` which is causing issues due to the escape characters like `\n` in the given path?

I'm using Click to parse my arguments and I prefer using the Pathlib module but I haven't figured out a good way to prevent those escape characters from messing things up the given path when it's passed to my code.

Example of code and what it's outputting.

```
import click
@click.command()
@click.argument("inpath")
def main(inpath):
    # "T:\not\a\good\path"
    print(inpath)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Run: `foo.txt T:\not\a\good\path`

Output:
`T:notagoodpath`

Comment: Can you clarify how your script takes a file path as an argument? If its a command line argument read from `sys.argv`, then there is no escaping needed. Escaping is only needed if this is a python string literal - usually that means a quoted string you typed into the program. But that wouldn't be an argument to the script...

Comment: IT would help to have an example that fails. Did `click` process an agrument and give you a string? You could `print(argument)` and see what you got. Or `print(repr(argument))` and post it here so we can see it.

Comment: @tdelaney Updated my post with some code.  Here I'm simply printing out what the `inpath` argument is passing.  But it's representative of the issue I'm having.  It's not passing along a literal string.

Comment: @tdelaney BTW, I know this is probably a really simple problem.  I'm an experience coder, but I mainly code in a Unix environment.  But this windows path is really stumping me.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I reproduced the problem, but its shell problem, not a python one, at least in common linux shells. \ escapes the next character, so whoever runs the program would have to know to write `foo.py "T:\not\a\good\path"`. But any program run by the shell has the same issues. Of course, linxu avoids \ in file names. I don't have Windows up and running at the moment so don't know its rules but i think that there is no need to escape there. Which OS are you running on?

Comment: @tdelaney Oh I see, the path has to be wrapped in quotes.  So I'm developing on my Debian instance.  But I know this tool will be run on a Windows machine and has to accept Windows style paths.  So I'm just trying to make sure I'm handling the incoming path arguments properly to idiot proof it as much as possible.  I had assumed there was a pythonic way to handle arguments such as this.  But is the answer really expecting the user to wrap their paths in quotes?

Comment: This only applies when running on the command line where you need to consider the shell's string escape rules. Not a problem on Windows. If a user is entering a Windows path on a linux machine, then there is a problem. But that linux command line user should be expected to know that sort of thing, IMHO. Windows accepts forward slashes these days, and that should work fine. Python won't know that, for instance, `\n` was converted to `n`, so there isn't much it can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "r" prefix to make your string raw and interpret "\n" as 2 regular characters.

```
path = r"T:\not\a\good\path"
print(path)
```

The result will be

```
"T:\not\a\good\path"
```

Comment: But how do you enforce that from a user given argument.  That's the problem I'm having right now.

Comment: @Berkyjay - well, you don't. Those are rules for literal strings in the python program itself. Suppose your program is `foo.py T:\not\a\good\path`. That is a good path. Since python didn't parse it, there was no special treatment of `\n`. Its the two characters \ and n.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
@click.argument("inpath", type=click.Path(exists=False))

def main(inpath):
    # "T:\not\a\good\path"
    click.echo(click.format_filename(inpath))
```

Note: if you want to make sure the path exists, change exists to True.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately verifying the existence of a path isn't my issue.  It's that backslashes in a string are escape characters and can cause issues with examples like the one I gave.  I'm trying to figure out how best to handle windows paths passed as arguments.